# C# code to inject 64bit dll to process

Tags: c#, dll, x86-64, inject

I have a code to inject 32bit library(C++) to foreign 32bit process:

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(
          IntPtr hProcess,
          IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
          uint dwStackSize,
          UIntPtr lpStartAddress, // raw Pointer into remote process  
          IntPtr lpParameter,
          uint dwCreationFlags,
          out IntPtr lpThreadId
        );

        ...

        public static bool InjectDLL(Process p, string dll)
        {
            IntPtr bytesout;
            Int32 LenWrite = dll.Length + 1;
            IntPtr AllocMem = (IntPtr)VirtualAllocEx(p.Handle, (IntPtr)null, (uint)LenWrite, 0x1000, 0x40);
            WriteProcessMemory(p.Handle, AllocMem, dll, (UIntPtr)LenWrite, out bytesout);
            UIntPtr Injector = (UIntPtr)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
            IntPtr hThread = (IntPtr)CreateRemoteThread(p.Handle, (IntPtr)null, 0, Injector, AllocMem, 0, out bytesout);
            return true;
        }
```

But how to fix that code to inject 64 bit libraries to 64bit processes? Code above doesn't work to 64bit processes and dlls.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the dll you are trying to inject is a 64-bit process and/or dll?  Because there isn't a reason this shouldn't work.

Comment: yes, dll is 64 bit and process is 64 bit

Comment: @Robert - That is your problem. You need to make the injector a 64-bit application and/or dll. A 32-bit assembly or dll CANNOT interact with a 64-bit assembly or dll unless you want everything to be 32-bit. If that is the case compile everything to support 32-bit only. Of course Kernel32.dll is can be a 32-bit and 64-bit dll depending on its location.

Comment: You need to make sure the application calling `kernel32` is calling the 64-bit version not the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 1):

Your ***injector***, your target process and the DLL must all be x64.

The reason is because of this line:

```
GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
```

That will return the address of the x86 LoadLibrary() not the x64 address.